# На чем написана 1С?

Tags: c++, 1с

Зашел разговор про 1с и я услышал следующее мнение - что 1с написана на ЯП Русского разлива, т.е. даже буквы в этом ЯП Русские, так же этот гражданин приложил скрин (в конце поста).
Проясните ситуацию, на чем написана 1с, и если она все такие написана на C++, то каким боком относиться к ней ЯП на Русский манер?

Вообще любая инфа на этот счет будет интересна...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может это Google переводчик перевел? :D

Comment: Хз, кто это перевел. Я как бы не знаток в вопросе, но когда я услышал про кириллический ЯП - мне захотелось присесть...

Comment: А что такого страшного в русском языке в программировании? По большому счету, русифицировать тот же C++ - нет проблем, работа простейшая, буквально для начинающего программиста... но зачем? Мое искреннее мнение - наше счастье (и преимущество), что языки программирования англоязычные, так что мы воспринимаем их по сути как математические формулы, а не как инструкции на русском. Одного приведенного скриншота достаточно, чтобы это понять :)

Comment: @Harry Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Страшного - ничего, но и полезного - еще меньше. Остается мечтать о том, что бы и валюта и границы между странами стерлись, а там может и язык в более общий сольется, столько преград сразу рухнет... ух!

Comment: Не знаю, как насчет границ и языков в обыденной жизни, но у каждой науки - свой язык. Математика бы остановилась, если бы использовала обыденный язык. Писать словами "интеграл от a до b от ..." - нет уж, увольте... Как и программировать `пока (знач > предел) --знач;` или `попытаться если (знач == 0) бросить исключение("неверное значение") ; поймать (исключение&)...` - нет уж, в сад, все в сад...

Comment: В недалеком прошлом было несколько языков программирования на русском: Алмир, Аналитик, Рапира. Язык Лого традиционно переводится на язык той страны, в которой используется. | Как уже тут сказали, русифицировать C++ элементарно. Зацените, например, [боярский диалект](https://habr.com/post/41561/).

Comment: _язык в более общий сольется_ - угу, в китайский...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да не, в Китайский точно не сольется. Люди по своей натуре ленивые, поэтому сольется в что-то простое, например в какой нить новый диалект английского, где полторы буквы в "букваре"... :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

На скриншоте язык не на котором написана платформа 1С, а язык на котором пишутся её конфигурации. Сама 1С написана на C++.

Answer (score 12):

На самом деле, 1С написана на языке С++ в среде разработки MS Visual C++.

Это сведения разработчиков 1С:

> Платформа 1С: Предприятия 8 написана на MS Visual C++.
>
> При создании платформы использована собственная компонентная архитектура.
> Сервер 1С: Предприятия создан с использованием технологии COM+.
> Механизмы платформы содержат большое количество собственных технологических решений.

Answer (score 2):

Платформа 1C:Предприятие — это система с открытым прикладным исходным кодом, написанным на проприетарном языке, официально его называют «Встроенный язык программирования 1С:Предприятие», неофициально и коротко – «язык 1С». Сама платформа 1С:Предприятие 8 — это большое (более 10 миллионов строк кода) приложение на C++ (клиент, сервер и т.д.), JavaScript (веб-клиент), и, с недавних пор еще и Java.

Answer (score 1):

На скриншоте язык написания конфигураций 1С, как писали выше платформа базируется на C++ технологиях, английский синтаксис в данном примере появился из за того, что язык написания конфигураций поддерживает помимо русского ещё много вариаций (в т.ч. английский)
поэтому можно написать даже в рамках одной функции строку на эстонском, название функции на румынском и т.д. (хотя смысла в этом абсолютно нет)